# Rails ActiveRecord regex validation of non-mandatory fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I'd like to validate a field with regex and also allow it to be blank (to accept an empty string). So far, the only thing I managed is to write a regex that allows an empty string, like:

```
validates :field,
          format: { with: /\A([a-z]+|)\z/i }
```

Now, this can't be a proper way - this seems like an ugly hack. I'd like to know if there's another (proper) approach?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[allow_blank](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#allow_blank) should work.  (There is also [allow_nil](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#allow_nil) for accepting nil values only (not an empty string))

```
validates :field,
          format: { with: /\A([a-z]+|)\z/i }, :allow_blank => true
```

Comment: Ah, beautiful, I knew it was RT(F)M issue after all! =)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the alternation... you can use the '*' quantifier to specify 'zero or more' occurrences. Also, I'd use '\w' rather than  [a-z]...  this will catch alphanumerics.

```
 validates :field,
      format: { with: /\A(\w*)\z/i }
```

Comment: I've put `[a-z]` just as an example, but I'd rather not use `*` there. `:allow_blank` was perfect, as it allows both `nil` and empty strings.